# how can I hide a pendo guide after the user logs out (single-page application)?

Tags: javascript, pendo

how can I programmatically hide a pendo guide after the user logs out, without refreshing the page (single-page application) ?

https://developers.pendo.io/docs/?bash#guides-and-guide-center

`pendo.stopGuides()` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You asked this question, tagged it with [guide], the system asked you if you really wanted to create a tag, and you said yes. Did you really mean it...? [We fought hard to kill that ambiguous tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290063/split-guide-into-more-specific-tags). I see your use case is different from the ones that were there when the meta was handled. Do you really need a tag for pendo _guides_? Are there pendo guide experts out there? I'll remove the tag for now; please try to choose from existing tags going forward.

Comment: The problem is, of course, that since you've created the tag with this question 4 other, low-rep people have tagged their terrible questions with [guide], looking for guidelines or other hand-holding help...

Comment: Hey @Chris, did you figure it out? I need to do this as well (close pendo guides from JS using the `pendo` object)

Comment: Hi @Nico. Gosh, I assume we found a solution and I'm bummed I didn't document it here. Now I no longer have access to that code as I'm working for a different company.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for looking into it and replying. It seems to be working for me (ie. `pendo.stopGuides()` closes open guides)